# What is the end of here string?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, here-string

It seemed to me that the end of a here string is newline. I realize I am wrong:

```
$ cat <<< hello world
cat: world: No such file or directory
```

What can signify the end of a here string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [syntax of a here string is](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings):

> ```
> <<< word
> ```

where [a *word* is a sequence of characters treated as a unit by the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-word), delimited by whitespace. That could be a single regular word (`hello`), a single- or double-quoted string (`'hello world'`, `"hello world"`), a parameter or command substitution (`$foo`, `$(...)`), something assembled with backslash escapes, or a combination of those joined together.

You can have multiple here-documents or here-strings on a single line, so the end of the line can't work as the *only* delimiter, though it will end there if not already (unless the newline is backslash-escaped).

You would get the effect you wanted with

```
cat <<<'hello world'
```

or

```
cat <<<hello\ world
```

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, you're right, there's no word-splitting there at all.

Comment: `<<<` comes from `zsh` (and the Unix variant of `rc`), and `$IFS` was never involved there (nor in `ksh93` nor `mksh` nor `yash` which also copied that operator) but in `bash` versions prior to 4.4, unquoted expansions in the word after `<<<` were subject to word splitting (and the resulting words joined with space) which is why you do need to write it as `cat <<< "$var"` if you want to support bash versions 4.3 or older. That was fixed in 4.4

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

> [n]<<<**word**

The end is one word, not multiple words. So in this example, the first word is `hello` and terminates the here string. The next word is `world`, it is just an ordinary argument to `cat`, and `cat` assumes it is a file name to read.

You could write it more clearly this way:

```
$ cat world <<< hello
```